# ¿Como leer múltiples valores , de sensores a tra vez de puerto serial y separarlas en visual c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino

Buenas tardes compañeros , actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación en visual studio , que me permita leer los valores de 8 sensores , e logrado la conexion serial y la lectura de los mismo , pero nose como separar las señales que recibo para que aparezcan en diferente txt respectivamente , hasta ahora solo puedo leer las señales y mostrarlas en un solo txt , alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto.

```
 `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;//biblioteca para puertos seriales 

namespace Minisumo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private delegate void DelegadoAcceso(String accion);//el delegado me permite actualizar los valores en tiempo real y que no se mantenga estatico
        private String strBufferIn;
        private String strbufferOut;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AccesoForm(String accion)
        {
            strBufferIn = accion;
            //----------------------------------Aqui llegan los datos
            TxtDatosRecibidos.Text = strBufferIn;//los datos recibido se muestran en el txt datos recibidos
            //----------------------------------
        }

        private void AccesoInterrupcion(String accion)//acceso de interrupcion para el delegado
        {
            DelegadoAcceso Var_DelegadoAcceso;
            Var_DelegadoAcceso = new DelegadoAcceso(AccesoForm);
            object[] arg = { accion };
            base.Invoke(Var_DelegadoAcceso , arg);


        }

        private void BtnBuscarPuertos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//comandos para buscar puertos
        {
            String[] PuertosDisponibles = SerialPort.GetPortNames();//busca puertos disponibls y los aloja en variable names

            CboPuertos.Items.Clear();//busqueda de puertod disponibles 
            foreach (String puerto_simple in PuertosDisponibles)
            {
                CboPuertos.Items.Add(puerto_simple);
            }
            if (CboPuertos.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                CboPuertos.SelectedIndex = 0;
                MessageBox.Show("SELECCIONAR PUERTO DE TRABAJO");
                BtnConectar.Enabled = true;
            }else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NINGUN PUERTO DETECTADO");
                CboPuertos.Items.Clear();
                CboPuertos.Text="                         ";
                strBufferIn = "";
                strbufferOut = "";
                BtnConectar.Enabled = false;
                BtnEnviarDatos.Enabled = false;

            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         strBufferIn="";
         strbufferOut = "";
            BtnConectar.Enabled = false;
            BtnEnviarDatos.Enabled = false;




    }

        private void BtnConectar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//funcion para conectar con el puerto escogido
        {
            try{
                if (BtnConectar.Text=="CONECTAR")
                {
                    SpPuertos.BaudRate=Int32.Parse(CboBaudRate.Text);
                    SpPuertos.DataBits = 8;//cantidad de bits de la conexion
                    SpPuertos.Parity = Parity.None;
                    SpPuertos.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                    SpPuertos.PortName = CboPuertos.Text;//nombre del puerto ala tex Cbo puertos

                    try//el try an caths me permite desconectar y conectar los puertos necesarios
                    {
                        SpPuertos.Open();
                        BtnConectar.Text = "DESCONECTAR";
                        BtnEnviarDatos.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    catch(Exception exc)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else if(BtnConectar.Text=="DESCONECTAR")
                {
                    SpPuertos.Close();
                    BtnConectar.Text = "CONECTAR";
                    BtnEnviarDatos.Enabled =false;//sentencia que cancela la accion de envio de datos

                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message.ToString());

            }
        }


        private void BtnEnviarDatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//sentencia de envio de datos al precionar el boton envio de datos
        {
            try
            {
                SpPuertos.DiscardInBuffer();
                strbufferOut = TxtEnviarDatos.Text;
                SpPuertos.Write(strbufferOut);

            }
            catch (Exception )
            {

            }

        }

        private void DatoRecibido(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            AccesoInterrupcion(SpPuertos.ReadExisting());
           /* String Data_in = SpPuertos.ReadExisting();
            MessageBox.Show(Data_in);
            TxtDatosRecibidos.Text = Data_in;*/
        }

        private void TxtDatosRecibidos_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
`

    #define s1 14
#define s2 15
#define s3 16
#define s4 17
#define s5 18
#define s6 19
#define s7 20
#define s8 21
int sensor [8];


void setup() {
  pinMode (s1, INPUT);
  pinMode (s2, INPUT);
  pinMode (s3, INPUT);
  pinMode (s4, INPUT);
  pinMode (s5, INPUT);
  pinMode (s6, INPUT);
  pinMode (s7, INPUT);
  pinMode (s8, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int se1=map(analogRead(s1),0,1023,0,255);
  int se2=map(analogRead(s2),0,1023,0,255);
  int se3=map(analogRead(s3),0,1023,0,255);
  int se4=map(analogRead(s4),0,1023,0,255);
  int se5=map(analogRead(s5),0,1023,0,255);
  int se6=map(analogRead(s6),0,1023,0,255);
  int se7=map(analogRead(s7),0,1023,0,255);
  int se8=map(analogRead(s8),0,1023,0,255);
  sensor[0]=se1;
  sensor[1]=se2;
  sensor[2]=se3;
  sensor[3]=se4;
  sensor[4]=se5;
  sensor[5]=se6;
  sensor[6]=se7;
  sensor[7]=se8;

for(int i=0;i<8 ; i++){
    Serial.print(sensor[i]);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();

}
```

Comment: te invito a que leas como preguntar, y agrega un poco de tu codigo, retornando a tu pregunta debes asegurarte que en la lectura de cada sensor se tenga un header identificador, 0xAA... OxA1, etc.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta , es que no se guardo mi código disculpe.

Comment: Como se pondria este identificador en arduino y cual seria  el comando para leerlo en visual

Comment: para cada sensor hay una entradra, en la tarjeta de arduino esta impreso A1...An, ejemplo int tempSensorPin = A1;  //Sensor temperatura  tu funcion sera analogRead(tempSensorPin); //el valor de A1 es una suposicion todo depende de donde este conectado

Comment: Ya lo hice pero me genera un problema al momento de delcarar mi base.Invoke(Var_DelegadoAcceso , arg);